delaying or speeding up drm/kms with amdgpu driver?
I have a amdgpu, using the open source driver. amdgpu driver claims to do early kms by default, but the early is very late. Exactly 2.5s!
I wouldn't care much but it breaks and delays my disk encryption password prompt.
the laptop already boots with EFI video which is perfectly usable and correct. then DRM/KMS loads, and screw ups the size and fonts for the tty. Then sd-vconsole starts and corrects it. Hence I'm trying to either delay kms or force it to be really early.
things that failed:

forcing edid

- # get-edid > myedid.bin
- do the dance to put file in initfs
- adding `drm.edid_firmware=edid/myedid.bin` to kernel parameters

it fails with "invalid firmware" but doesn't matter, i still get the error right on top of my sd-encrypt prompt, so it would not help move it early/later.

early kms hook.

tried this weird mkinitcpio.conf list for the hooks
HOOKS=(systemd kms autodetect modconf keyboard sd-vconsole block sd-encrypt microcode lvm2 filesystems fsck)

still happens late.

forcing the right tty size/font

thinking i can't win, i try to join kms and just tell it what to set things to when it comes crashing in.
Added any combination of video=efifb fbcon=font:iso01-12x22 fbcon=nodefer video=eDP-1:1920x1200@60.03 (which is what sd-vconfig sets)
it still ignores the font, and while it always set the display to the right resolution, the virtual resolution for the tty get's cut in 1/4 which breaks all the text for a while. And still starts at 2.5s into the boot.

bundling amdgpu firmware in initfs

reading on https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8789979.html i added FILES=(/usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/*) to mkinitcpio.conf
nothing changes.

I haven’t tried any of this, but https://hansdegoede.dreamwidth.org/28291.html might provide some useful ideas.

@StephenKitt that might be the best solution! but mkinitcpio doesn't have a way to remove a module included by default... as far as i could find.
